# Cannot get Actionable Notifications callback on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, unusernotificationcenter

I have an iOS App that's pushing notifications (for example when the user is entering a geographic region).
I have also a Watch App that gets these notifications when the iPhone is locked. I have 2 Actions in these notifications ("Call", "Go to"), they are correctly displayed in the Apple Watch notification but when the user touches one of these action the callback

```
userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

from my **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate** is never called!

Here's the code in the iOS App:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Register local notification (alert & sound)
    // They are used to notify the user when entering/exiting a monitored region
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
        if let theError = error {
            NSLog("\(#function) error when request localNotification \(theError.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if !granted {
                NSLog("\(#function) Warning local notification not granted")
            }
        }

     })

    var actions = [UNNotificationAction]()
    actions.append(UNNotificationAction(identifier: "CallId", title: "Call", options:[] )) // UNNotificationActionOptions.authenticationRequired
    actions.append(UNNotificationAction(identifier: "CallId2", title: "Go To", options:[UNNotificationActionOptions.authenticationRequired] ))

    let notificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "MonitoringRegionCategory", actions: actions, intentIdentifiers: [],  options: [])
    let categories: Set = [notificationCategory]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories(categories)
    return true
}
```

the code to send the notification (in the iOS App)

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "title"
    content.subtitle = "subtitle"

    var message:String
    if isEntering {
        message = String(format: NSLocalizedString("POI less than %d meters", comment: ""), Int(poi.poiRegionRadius))
    } else {
        message = String(format: NSLocalizedString("POI more than %d meters", comment: ""), Int(poi.poiRegionRadius))
    }

    content.body = message
    content.badge = 1
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "MonitoringRegionCategory"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: AppDelegate.LocalNotificationId.monitoringRegionId, content:content, trigger: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
        if let theError = error {
            NSLog("\(#function) Error with notification add \(theError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
```

In the WatchApp to code to register and implement the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        NSLog("\(#function)")


        // Perform any final initialization of your application.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
}

  // MARK: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        NSLog("\(#function)")

        completionHandler()
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        NSLog("\(#function)")
        completionHandler(.alert)
    }
```

Any idea why userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) is never called when the user select one of the button from the Notification?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or make progress on this issue?  I'm looking for more information about this exact issue myself.

Comment: Have you got any fix for this issue?

Comment: One finding - If you tap on notification instead of interactive buttons ```Call``` then ```didReceive``` method will be called. For some reason interactive buttons are not triggering callback.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding the `UNNotificationAction` as a `.foreground` category. You've to change following line to fix it:

```
var actions = [UNNotificationAction]()
actions.append(UNNotificationAction(identifier: "CallId", title: "Call", options:[.foreground]))
actions.append(UNNotificationAction(identifier: "CallId2", title: "Go To", options:[.authenticationRequired]))
```

`.foreground` will launch you app and invoke `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` method. You can handle your actions and redirections in this method for the actionable button. Here is the example:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
     switch response.actionIdentifier.lowercased() {
        case "call":
            WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["CallInterface"], contexts: nil)
        default: break
     }
     completionHandler()
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Bhanu, just to confirm the delegate in your case is still ExtensionDelegate? Because I have it set to foreground and it doesn't look like didReceive is called.